# How can I have a visually active (checked), disabled toggle button in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, checked, disabled-control

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/LWEB9SUaqT)

I have a `data-toggle` checkbox group, where I'd like one (or more) of the options to be checked, yet disabled.

Is there a built-in visual style, or would I need custom CSS?  This doesn't seem to work:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

  <label class="btn btn-primary  disabled">
    <input class="form-control" name="beard" value="fluffy" disabled="" type="checkbox"> Fluffy
  </label>

  <label class="btn btn-primary  disabled">
    <input class="form-control" name="beard" value="scraggly" disabled="" type="checkbox"> Scraggly
  </label>

  <label class="btn btn-primary  active disabled">
    <input class="form-control" name="beard" value="pointy" disabled="" checked="" type="checkbox"> Pointy
  </label>

</div>
```

Functionally, I suppose the last option is checked, but visually it appears no differently than the disabled options.

Yes, I am looking for checkboxes styled as buttons (as Bootstrap does).  Must avoid using any additional JS.

Comment: I think, visually, the disabled class overwrites all other BS classes. So I don't think this is possible with the default classes BS give you. You'd have to write your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any `.btn` element with `.disabled` will have its `box-shadow` removed by precedence. You can change that by adding your own simple style to be applied:

```
.btn.disabled.active{
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.275);
}
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/2agX9z7cRx)

Change the `box-shadow` parameters to fit your needs.

Comment: @JasonBassett *My* example is a fork of the example provided by the OP.

Comment: @JasonBassett thats how checkboxes in bootstrap look when styled as buttons. This answers the question perfectly, I'm not sure why it was downvoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote anyones answer but yes, I didn't catch that at first glance. He's using buttons as checkboxes.